# How to configure sublime text 3 to run python in the build section instead of cmd?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have sublime text 3 but I'm trying to run Python 2.7 instead of the default 3.3. Is there an easy way to do this? What I have is a Python_cmd.sublime-build file in Packages/usr with

```
{
"cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "c:/python27/python.exe", "$file"],
"selector": "source.python",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "$file_dir"
```

}

but what this does is run the file by opening cmd. I want the error and results to be in sublime text 3 itself without opening a cmd.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `start cmd /k`

```
{
     "cmd": ["c:/python27/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
     "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
     "selector": "source.python"
}
```